# Templates instantiation between libraries

Tags: c++, templates, shared-libraries

I have 2 different libraries which include the same header with templated class:

***Header.hpp***:

```
template<typename T>
class Tpl1
{
public:
    static int field;
};

template<typename T>
int Tpl1<T>::field(7);
```

***module1.cpp*** (shared lib 1):

```
Tpl1<float> tpl;
std::cout << "f1: " << &tpl.field << std::endl;
```

***module2.cpp*** (executable):

```
Tpl1<float> tpl;
std::cout << "f2: " << &tpl.field << std::endl;
```

So, in my linux, console application with:
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3

As a result, I see the same pointer addresses. Everything is fine!

Now imagine native android application built with android ndk r8e and gcc 4.7 toolchain.

Except that two modules/libraries we also have an java wrapper which loads that two native libraries. And WHOA! In android I see **DIFFERENT** addresses!

So, compiler for native android application doesn't remove the same templates instantiations. The reason I see is that for PC build all libraries are linked into single binary file and for android, the libraries are loaded dynamically into java application.

Are there any ways to have only one version of the same template? The only version I see is to link all libraries into single one and link it in java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with template instantiation, really! During link time, unresolved symbols get resolved and duplicated symbols, e.g., from
template instantiation or inline function which are not inlined (e.g. because their address is taken), are conflated. When using shared libraries linking hsppens at a time when it is unknown which other shared libraries will be loaded and symbols between shared lobraries are not necessarily conflated.

The C++ stsndard makes no requirements with respect to shared libraries and you'll need to resolve problems probably in system specific manners. Generally it seems to work to factor the shared symbols into another shared library which is used from the others.

Comment: Hello, I am second author of the question. Thanks for the answer, but we asking, is there some *hack*, to remove equal symbols from shared libraries? Maybe there is some post-compile utility..

Comment: I'm not aware of any utilities doing that although I could imagine an ELF tool removing dedicated symbols (I don't know anything about non-ELF systems). What _might_ work if you don't use the template with too many different types is to put the problematic template definitions into a source file and to explicitly instantiate the relevant specializations.